# "Truncation from int to char" not producing any result

Tags: c++, char, int

My code can compile but it doesn't return the character asked and it also does not follow the else statement since it will cout the error message after any input from the true if statement. Beginner in C++ so any help is appreciated.

```
// Python Challenge 2.cpp : This program will take a line of text from the user and then translate each letter 2 over in the alphabet.
//

#include "stdafx.h"

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
char chChar; 
char chChar2;
char chChar_a;
char chChar_b;
int main()
{ 
    //This takes the one letter input from the user:
    cout << "Type in a lowercase letter: ";
    cin >> chChar;

    //for letters a-x
    if ((int)chChar >= 97 && (int)chChar <= 120)
        char chChar2 = (int)chChar + 2; 
        cout <<  "is now: " << chChar2 << endl;

        //for the letter y
        if ((int)chChar == 121)
        {
            char chChar_a = '97';
            cout <<  "is now: " << chChar_a << endl;
        }

        //for the letter z 
        if ((int)chChar == 122)
        {
            char chChar_b = '98';
            cout <<  "is now: " << chChar_b << endl;
        }   

    //for everything else
    else
        cout << "Error: type in a lowercase letter." << endl;

        return 0;   
}
```

Comment: Your if-statement lacks brackets

Comment: `char chChar_a = '97';` this doesn't seem right..

Comment: You don't need to cast `char` to `int` to do arithmetic on them, and '97' should be 97 (or preferably 'a'), and '98' should be 98 (or preferably 'b'). You can also replace 120 with 'x', 121 with 'y', and 122 with 'z'.

Comment: @AlexD I meant { } after the first `if`.

Comment: So many globals and so many unnecessary casts.

Comment: @PaulR that's how a big project I was once involved crashed: lots of globals and slowdowns (or compiler issues) due to unnecessary casts

Comment: If you use an editor that knows how to indent, you'll notice that the `else` belongs to `if ((int)chChar == 122)`, i.e. you get the error output for every input except 'z'.

Comment: So i got rid of my truncation errors by switching the 97 to 'a' abd the 98 to 'b' but it still doesnt output the new letter

Comment: Ok so the program is functioning fine, with the exception of the Error message. I know I will have to work with the brackets somehow but using Visual 2010 Express makes it difficult to see what the else is being attached to

Comment: @GeoffreyMason To re-indent the entire document, `Ctrl+k, Ctrl+d`. To re-indent the selection, `Ctrl+k, Ctrl+f`. This will indent the block structure properly.

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` statement is not correct: you forgot to create a block using `{ }` after it.

As it stands, the code does:

```
//for letters a-x
if ((int)chChar >= 97 && (int)chChar <= 120)
{
    char chChar2 = (int)chChar + 2; 
}
// Always runs the next part
cout <<  "is now: " << chChar2 << endl;
...
```

And the final `else` is attached to the `if` before it:

```
//for the letter z 
if ((int)chChar == 122)
{
    char chChar_b = '98';
    cout <<  "is now: " << chChar_b << endl;
}   
else
{
    cout << "Error: type in a lowercase letter." << endl;
}
```

To fix this, add the proper brackets `{ }`. An `if` without the brackets only conditionally executes the next statement, and not the block -- don't let indentations fool you: they have no meaning in C.

---

So, with this, your fixed code should look like:

```
//This takes the one letter input from the user:
cout << "Type in a lowercase letter: ";
cin >> chChar;

//for letters a-x
if ((int)chChar >= 97 && (int)chChar <= 120)
{
    char chChar2 = (int)chChar + 2; 
    cout <<  "is now: " << chChar2 << endl;

    //for the letter y
    if ((int)chChar == 121)
    {
        char chChar_a = '97';
        cout <<  "is now: " << chChar_a << endl;
    }

    //for the letter z 
    if ((int)chChar == 122)
    {
        char chChar_b = '98';
        cout <<  "is now: " << chChar_b << endl;
    }   
}
//for everything else
else
{
    cout << "Error: type in a lowercase letter." << endl;
}

return 0;
```

---

Starting from this, you can debug your code for further issues.

Comment: Thank you so much. I knew it had to deal with my brackets but was testing the different placements and wasn't understanding where I was going wrong. Seeing your solution helped teach me how to avoid this error in the future. Thank you.

Comment: Except now my statement for y and z do not work. Trying to fix it now. Will post the solution if I find it

Comment: To get the y and z to work, I had to add else in front of the if statement for z. The z statement now reads else if ((int)chChar == 122). All is working as should be.